# clone values when collecting an iterator into a vector

Tags: rust, iterator, ownership

I am writing a program which takes several lines of input from `stdin`. I read the line into a string and then split it and collect the words into a vector. This string (`buffer`) is reused on later lines so that I don't need to create a new string for each line of input.

However, when I try to compile my code I find that I cannot reuse the string because it is still borrowed.

```rust
let mut buffer = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).expect("failure reading stdin");
let mut info: Vec<&str> = buffer.trim().split(" ").collect(); // <-- immutable borrow of buffer
...
buffer.clear();  // <-- cannot borrow `buffer` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).expect("failure reading stdin");
```

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here as I thought that `info` would create &str's from the data in `buffer` (as &str implements copy). But either way I need to change my program to remove this borrow. The easiest way to do this seems to be to modify the offending line so that `info` owns the `&str`'s that it contains. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you just clone the input string?

Comment: @Victor yes I could. However, I would then leave a string sticking around for every new line I read in. I'm also trying to work out what's going on with memory and what owns what so creating a tonne of new strings just kicks that problem down the road until I use the data I've read in.

Answer (score 2):

This works (tested Rust 1.66.1) if you want `info` to be `Vec<String>` instead of `Vec<&str>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::from("I am an example of a string!");
    let info: Vec<_> = buffer.trim().split(' ').map(|x| x.to_string()).collect();

    buffer.clear();

    println!("Buffer cleared. Info content: {:?}", info);
}
```

Edit:

Keep in mind that `str` *doesn't* implement `Copy`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html

To my understanding, it's the [*reference*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html) that implements `Copy`, so you aren't actually getting a copy of the contents, just of the memory address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the reference. I've been coding rust on and off for the last couple of months and tbh I still don't totally understand how &str works so now's probably a good time to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

A `&str` is a reference to existing characters. Unless they are static, the characters must have an owner, typically the `String` type.

Your code has a single `String` that can own characters (`buffer`).

If you get a shared reference to the `String` using, for example, `let info: &str = buffer.as_str()` then you cannot modify the `String` while that reference exists. Specifically you cannot get a mutable reference to the `String` while any other reference to the `String` exists. A mutable reference must be the only reference to an owned instance.

The `split` method returns an iterator of `&str` which you then store in a `Vec`. Each of these `&str` objects is a reference into the owned `String` and they will exist as long as the `Vec` that contains them. While they exist you cannot get a mutable reference to modify `buffer`.

To allow the modification, you need to turn the shared references into new owned types (`String`) to store in the `Vec`, as shown in vellista's answer. `to_string` consumes a shared reference and returns a new owned instance.